# Is there a way to find files without match in the "find in path" menu in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

In grep I can use the `-L` / `--files-without-match` option to find files where the pattern cannot be found. Is there a similar option for IntelliJ?

I'm using IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option in IntelliJ IDEA Find in Path. Request is [welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).